# Error when render Visualforce page to excel

Tags: visualforce

i have vf pages that will render as excel file.
the data source is from custom controller.
the query return in pages is correct

## but after the data displayed in table, the page also generate like an error message:

> [{"displayName": "PrintTimesheet","name": "PrintTimesheet","viewstateSize": 4.42,"percentOfParent": 100.0,"percentOfTotalViewstate": 100.0,"leaf": false,"isGroupable": false,"identityCode": "bd54f935a71a96e8041db78385ec61e2","children": [{"displayName": "Component Tree","name": "Component Tree","viewstateSize": 0.44,"percentOfParent": 10.0,"percentOfTotalViewstate": 10.0,"leaf": true,"iconCls": "task","isGroupable": false,"identityCode": "3f49c4e4fbf91b1848840255adb239d1"},{"displayName": "State","name": "State","viewstateSize": 4.13,"percentOfParent": 93.0,"percentOfTotalViewstate": 93.0,"leaf": false,"isGroupable": false,"identityCode": "d80c09f6c50cf97f2876eb21a2ecec27","children": [{"displayName": "Expressions","name": "Expressions","viewstateSize": 0.77,"percentOfParent": 19.0,"percentOfTotalViewstate": 17.0,"leaf": true,"iconCls": "task","isGroupable": false,"identityCode": "6521e758750cd97456ee87ea83dfa024"},{"displayName": "Controllers","name": "Controllers","viewstateSize": 1.19,"percentOfParent": 29.0,"percentOfTotalViewstate": 27.0,"leaf": false,"isGroupable": false,"identityCode": "1ae68016a94c8a724fdaf48ca6478531","children": [{"displayName": "TimesheetForAdminController","name": "TimesheetForAdminController","type": "Page printtimesheet Controller","viewstateSize": 1.19,"percentOfParent": 100.0,"percentOfTotalViewstate": 27.0,"leaf": false,"iconCls": "task","isGroupable": false,"identityCode": "6786a464e15996b8ebf96b161325cbfe","children": [{"displayName": "EmployeeName","name": "EmployeeName","type": "String","viewstateSize": 0.05,"percentOfParent": 4.0,"percentOfTotalViewstate": 1.0,"value": "bri","leaf": true,"iconCls": "task","isGroupable": false,"identityCode": "84df0fe02f47b043ef2a2e0a87ef477a"},{"displayName": "EndDate","name": "EndDate","type": "String","viewstateSize": 0.05,"percentOfParent": 4.0,"percentOfTotalViewstate": 1.0,"value": "","leaf": true,"iconCls": "task","isGroupable": false,"identityCode": "881cca0e8af585a6a416c316f062f540"},{"displayName": "StartDate","name": "StartDate","type": "String","viewstateSize": 0.05,"percentOfParent": 4.0,"percentOfTotalViewstate": 1.0,"value": "","leaf": true,"iconCls": "task","isGroupable": false,"identityCode": "d036f268ff5fb34bde16d42342bb7b96"},{"displayName": "ts [1]","name": "ts","type": "LIST","viewstateSize": 0.8,"percentOfParent": 67.0,"percentOfTotalViewstate": 18.0,"leaf": false,"isGroupable": true,"identityCode": "6477e7b19026d8e88186bf38d7f63073","children": [{"displayName": "0","name": "0","type": "Timesheet__c","viewstateSize": 0.64,"percentOfParent": 80.0,"percentOfTotalViewstate": 14.0,"leaf": false,"iconCls": "task","isGroupable": false,"identityCode": "f5c71efd2825940713aeb4f5885f01bb","children": [{"displayName": "Employee_Name__c","name": "Employee_Name__c","type": "String","viewstateSize": 0.11,"percentOfParent": 17.0,"percentOfTotalViewstate": 2.0,"value": "a05N0000002emCfIAI","leaf": true,"iconCls": "task","isGroupable": false,"identityCode": "15bd238dcf2e9af2ca363fac4b7094ef"},{"displayName": "Transport_Type__c","name": "Transport_Type__c","type": "String","viewstateSize": 0.11,"percentOfParent": 17.0,"percentOfTotalViewstate": 2.0,"value": "Return Trip","leaf": true,"iconCls": "task","isGroupable": false,"identityCode": "376f7572bcfc6e933fcdbbcdb21950ec"},{"displayName": "Project_Allowance_IDR__c","name": "Project_Allowance_IDR__c","type": "String","viewstateSize": 0.17,"percentOfParent": 27.0,"percentOfTotalViewstate": 4.0,"value": "40000.00","leaf": true,"iconCls": "task","isGroupable": false,"identityCode": "ff952400966d21d52fa3e4a48fba34ce"},{"displayName": "Project_Name__r","name": "Project_Name__r","type": "String","viewstateSize": 0.31,"percentOfParent": 48.0,"percentOfTotalViewstate": 7.0,"value": "Project__c:{Name=Phincon - Imp...","leaf": true,"iconCls": "task","isGroupable": false,"identityCode": "fcef87ecb5ff55c6d01e71513d9ca84d"},{"displayName": "Timesheet_End_DateTime__c","name": "Timesheet_End_DateTime__c","type": "String","viewstateSize": 0.13,"percentOfParent": 20.0,"percentOfTotalViewstate": 3.0,"value": "Wed Oct 22 10:00:00 GMT 2014","leaf": true,"iconCls": "task","isGroupable": false,"identityCode": "c3e7a1b7ddbdbefcd3be6938c930cc72"},{"displayName": "Timesheet_Start_DateTime__c","name": "Timesheet_Start_DateTime__c","type": "String","viewstateSize": 0.13,"percentOfParent": 20.0,"percentOfTotalViewstate": 3.0,"value": "Wed Oct 22 01:00:00 GMT 2014","leaf": true,"iconCls": "task","isGroupable": false,"identityCode": "282806a2ff4b18db9d99d54e2445c75c"},{"displayName": "Activity__c","name": "Activity__c","type": "String","viewstateSize": 0.09,"percentOfParent": 14.0,"percentOfTotalViewstate": 2.0,"value": "Testing","leaf": true,"iconCls": "task","isGroupable": false,"identityCode": "9244277a2aabd301f26ebb9398ed8617"},{"displayName": "Employee_Name__r","name": "Employee_Name__r","type": "String","viewstateSize": 0.28,"percentOfParent": 44.0,"percentOfTotalViewstate": 6.0,"value": "Employee__c:{Name=Brian, Id=a0...","leaf": true,"iconCls": "task",&quot..

this happened in or company production sandbox.
wen i tried create a same vf page in my developer edition org, the message is not generated.
how to fix this ?
please help

regards,

Willy Chiandra

Comment: when i render as .doc , the error message is not show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres not a lot of detail here, but the data structure you have here represents the developer mode/viewstate data that we get when developing visualforce when we have the developer mode turned on.

I would suggest you turn off/uncheck these items on your user record for the sandbox environment.

[image]

Comment: thanks Dacology,
it's working fine after i disabled development mode.

Comment: Great! Developer mode can cause some unexpected behavior sometimes.